# Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_setopt()

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.6, magento

every thing has been working well on my localhost but when i have uploaded it in the server after that whenever i am trying to login my admin panel then it is giving the following error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_setopt() in D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\lostandfound.co.in\nityapusta\magento\jewellery\lib\Varien\Http\Adapter\Curl.php on line 87

Answer (score 5):

You have to enable CURL and restart you XAMPP/WAMP/MAMP.

1. Go to php.ini file.
2. Enable Curl by uncommenting the semicolan before "extension=php_curl.dll".
3. Restart your server - XAMPP/WAMP/MAMP.

If you are using live server, contact your hosting provider support to get help on this.

Answer (score 3):

You may be using windows 7/8 64 bit, there is a solution: replace your extension php_curl.dll with this file: http://www.mediafire.com/download/qwgdzgccthzwc15/php_curl-5.3.13-VC9-x64.zip

it works for me.

Comment: +1, this worked for me as well. Just downloaded the file, replaced the file in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\ext and restarted.

Comment: Try this solution if you already have curl enabled. Worked for me!

Comment: Windows 8.1 php5.3.13, Already enabled php_curl was not working. This solution solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

Enable Curl by uncommenting the semicolan before "extension=php_curl.dll" in php.ini file and
you need to restart your Apache server for the changes to take effect. I had similar problem and I had to restart the Apache to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
After so many hours of trying finally i found it's solution and which are given below .
Step1-Navigate to your php folder in XAMPP or WAMP or In WebHost Control panel.
Step2-Find the php.ini file.
step3-Find ";extension=php_curl.dll".
Step4-Remove ";" from ";extension=php_curl.dll".
Step5-look like this extension=php_curl.dll.
Step6-Save it.

That's it...
```

Comment: For you two guys, make sure you're using php v5.3.13 -- I think 5.4.x doesn't work...  testing similar problem on WAMP server now